# jQuery.getScript is not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$.getScript` is not working even when the mobile device has internet connection.
How can we write jquery.getscript for my below code? I am not able load my url in script because if mobile device has no internet my application is not started so I would like to include my url if internet connection is available. Can anyone please correct my code?

```
if (states[networkState] == 'No network connection') {
    // Device with no network data connection
    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "Location unavailable";
} else {
    // code for getting current address using Lat/Longs

    $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true", function () {
        var geocoder;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latlng
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    var add = results[0].formatted_address;
                    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "Location : " + add;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "No Results found ";
                }
            } else {
                //document.getElementById("location").innerHTML="Geocoder failed due to: " + status;
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: is `networkState` a variable? if it's an array key, you reference it like `states.networkState` or `states['networkState']` instead.

Comment: There is no problem with states['networkState']. It is internet connection status. My problem is with $.getScript() function. Please suggest me how to use $.getScript() in my code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get the "Geocoder failed" alert? Does it do anything? Does it not work only on the mobile device, or neither on desktop browsers? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: you `getScript()` function works fine [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q7cvm/7/)

Comment: @KawineshSK You mean works if you remove almost everything?

Comment: The problem may lie with that the returned data from $.getScript() is actually undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/remus/h44Rs/

Comment: @Juhana No the question is **getScript** not working but thats not the case here there are some Errors in the JS code.

Comment: what errors in JS code ?

Comment: you can't use ajax requests that way in jsfiddle. you have to fake it and construct your own response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE:

actually the stuff at the bottom here is not going to work.  Google is smart...the response is coming back empty BUT they are smartER even... if you look at their API docs you can see that they allow you to specify a callback in your request.  So you would do this:

```
jQuery('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=address"/>')
```

Note the reference to `callback=address`

The moral of the story is read the API docs :D

## The stuff I hypothesized but didn't work:

It's failing because something isn't defined yet. But  if you look in the script  that is returned you'll see that it is dynamically creating a script tag (yes another one) from https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/15/4/main.js.

You could:

1. load that script in your `$.getScript()` callback and then on the callback to that call your address function.

   Since the URL above might be dynamically generated you might want to use a regex to parse the first getScript response and then pull the URL out of that response for your callback.  You should consider using `$.ajax` here instead of `$.getScript` so you can use the `cache` result otherwise it will use a random number to re-request the script new everytime.
2. or you might consider using a timer in your callback to look for existence of a new variable or object to know it is done loading (whatever it was failing on before)

Comment: Thank you for your response. can you please show one example.